# How to clone a repo from BitBucket into PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, bitbucket

I have PyCharm 2021.3.3 installed and I've got an account on BitBucket.

I'm aware BitBucket recommends using "App Passwords" and I've been able to successfully utilise this when using command line Git yesterday. I've set another password up specifically for PyCharm, but neither that, nor my standard login password are working.

The process I'm following:

- Open PyCharm, click Get from VCS.
- Paste the repo URI into the URL
  box.
- Click Clone. I am prompted with an Atlassian branded login box
  asking for my email and password. I enter them.
- I am then taken back to PyCharm where it asks a second time for the same information. I
  enter it again.

No combination of using my regular password, nor the app password in either box is working.

Can someone please help me to understand what's going wrong with this?

Answer (score 4):

The main issue here is the fact, that since March 1, 2022, Bitbucket Cloud users will no longer be able to use their account passwords when using Basic authentication for Git over HTTPS. The link to the announcement is here:
[https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity#:~:text=Starting%20Sep%2013%2C%202021%2C%20new,to%20use%20Bitbucket%20app%20passwords](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity#:%7E:text=Starting%20Sep%2013%2C%202021%2C%20new,to%20use%20Bitbucket%20app%20passwords).

To be able to clone the Bibucket repo in PyCharm, new ***app password*** must be created.

The instructions for the app password creation are provided here:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-an-app-password/

After the creation of app password, go to your Bitbucket repo, press the Clone button and copy the text (it starts with 'git clone' and includes the username plus the repo url). Paste the text in the PyCharm dialog box that has popped up after pressing 'Get from VCS' button.

Then the PyCharm dialog box pops up with the user name prepopulated. Enter the new app password. The repo will be cloned in PyCharm as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the 'git clone' command to the URL allowed this to work. You can't just paste the HTTPS address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).